# Dynamic approach in retrieving attribute from VO

Tags: java

There is a POJO VO with a series of attributes that follow the JavaBeans standard.

I am strategizeing an approach to retrieve attributes dynamically.

For example lets assume, attribute name, address and zip is now needed form the VO.

How can I invoke the getName(), getAddress() and getZip() dynamically?

I have an approach where i can send in externally the getters as strings in a List and invoking them via reflection, wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

Thank you

Comment: Yes, use an [`Introspector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html). Or, if just Java 8, just use a lambda.

Comment: Why not use a Map? No need to ever change your code.